# Removing Rows based on duplicate keywords using Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am looking to find an answer on how to remove a row that has a duplicate keyword or IP address. For example.

```
169.146.25.111 1412969662.95 This is just to make it unique
169.146.25.111 1412969662.95 This data doesn't matter
169.146.25.111 1712515362.95 This is all different
169.146.25.112 1412969662.95 Don't care what's here
169.146.25.111 1315125152.95 erroneous information
```

So I want it to match the IP Address, and then search the following lines, if it finds the IP address at the beginning of the line, to remove that row.  This is what I've been trying to use.

```
Find what:
^(\S+)(.*?)$\s+(?=.*^\1).*?$
Replace With:
\1\2
```

Desired Result

```
169.146.25.111 1412969662.95 This is just to make it unique
169.146.25.112 1412969662.95 Don't care what's here
```

I am looking for an answer to this in Regex please. I know it can be easily done with sort or awk, but I've been trying hard to get it to work with Regex and it's hurting my brain. Thank you

Comment: Was the intent here is to keep the first line and remove duplicate lines? or remove duplicate lines and keep last line?

Comment: I have a file with a whole bunch of IP addresses, and I need to only retain the rows of data that have unique IP addresses.  So I want to remove lines that have duplicate IP addresses, even if the remainder of the line is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example for the ip address, with a global search and an empty replacement string *(dotall option must be unchecked)*:

```
^(\S++).*\R(?=(?>.*\R)*?\1 )
```

pattern description:

```
^              # start of the line anchor
(\S++)         # captures all non whitespace characters 
               # the possessive quantifier '++' forbids backtracking
.*             # all until the newline character (dotall mode disable)
\R             # a newline (whatever the system \r, \r\n, \n)
(?=            # open a lookahead test
    (?>        # open an atomic group (forbids backtracking once closed)
        .*\R   # a line (with the next newline)
    )*?        # the atomic group may occur zero or more times
    \1         # backreference to the capture group
)              # close the lookahead
```

Comment: This works beautifully thank you, now for the important part is for me to tweak it and to figure out WHY it works, even with your descriptive comments I'm still a little hazy.  I appreciate the fast and speedy response, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

based on the OP's example pattern and the data provided, works for contiguous lines only

```
^(\S++)(.*)(?:\R\1.*)+
```

and replace w/ `\1\2`,  dotall option must be unchecked as well
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/33)